# Underground Wiring Through Basement Wall

Tags: electrical, conduit, underground

I am installing an RV pad with full hookups along one side of my home.  The service panel I plan to connect to is very close by in the basement.  All the info I have found on underground wiring assumes it is exiting above ground through an LB box.  **Per code,** is it possible to directly exit the basement horizontally already underground?  If so, would I connect the appropriate conduit directly to the box on the inside?

As for feasibility, I am removing an extra egress window (extenive remodel) so I will have very easy access to both sides of the wall before I backfill.  Already plan to run the sewer through the new block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You certainly *can* exit/enter directly below ground.

One reason it's not commonly done is that when done that way, it's common for it to cause a leak, so consider where water entering the box via the conduit will drain to. Outside conduits are *defined* as wet, and usually live up to the definition. They fill with condensate even if they are made "perfectly watertight."

Duct seal (the gray non-hardening putty from the electrical aisle for sealing around wires in conduit, not the stuff from the HVAC aisle for sealing the outside of air ducts) can *help*, but is not going to hold pressure if there's several feet of water built up in the conduit, as will happen with a RV panel on the surface and a conduit entering the building several feet below grade. So your box will need a place to drain to, and the connections in it should be done in a wet location fashion.

If you're sure the ground water is always below the conduit entry point, you can have a weep hole to let condensate drain outside. But if the ground water level comes up to that level, water will weep in through it.

Or, you can come up to an LB and enter above ground, "the normal way." Your call.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes total sense.  The local water table averages 20 feet below surface per USGS and I'm planning on using RMC so I can go close to the surface.  Would the weep hole drain into say a gravel bed outside the wall, or add a vertical drain inside the wall like a compressed air system would use for periodic condensate?

Comment: The usual would be outside the wall. If you duct-seal both ends of the conduit that should cut down on air movement (reducing but not eliminating condensation)